# Cheap Wi-Fi + small mono display + a couple of buttons

Tags: wifi, automation, all-in-one

I am working on a one-off home automation project for personal use. The software is not in question (i.e., I can write the software to drive pretty much any kind of hardware out there).

I will have 2 or 3 physically separate, networked (via Wi-Fi) nodes, installed in **fixed locations** in my house. Each will access a shared server (already exists) via Wi-Fi, and accept input from the user via button/touch input.

In terms of interface, I could get by with a 16x2 character backlit mono LCD screen plus a couple of momentary contact buttons. A small touch screen + web browser would work just as well. I also need some kind of sound output. A simple buzzer/beeper would suffice, but an actual computer audio interface and small speaker would be acceptable as well. Among the options in this paragraph, I don't really have a preference, so it will come down to cost.

Size footprint isn't terribly important, but think wall-mounted panel, not computer workstation.

I have considered things like the Raspberry Pi + 16x2 LCD + Wi-Fi + buttons, which would run me about $100 for my minimum requirements. I'm hoping to find something cheaper than that, but I won't put a number on it that might be unrealistic.

Operating system is a don't care, as long as it supports the required hardware. I can program a µc if need be.

I've also considered touch screen devices such as used iPod Touches. Jiggering a web interface for my software is already planned. In general, I don't mind buying used hardware if it's likely to be reliable and give me at least a few years' life.

I **will** put the software on my mobile phone as well (as well as my PC), but I still need the fixed installations as I do not usually carry my mobile phone around with me when I'm in the house.

Comment: An arduino based system would probably be good. Arduino + WiFi shield + small character display + Buttons would not cost much. You will need to write some arduino code + a REST / Http api for your server though. I can expand on this and write an answer if you are interested in some more information.

Comment: @JonasCz If the hardware would be significantly cheaper than the ~$100 Raspberry Pi build I was considering in the question, please do put together an answer! There hasn't been much interest in this question, so if you write a good answer to this question, I'll accept it.

Comment: Yup, It should be cheaper (~$50). I'll write up an answer when I have time. Other people have done this with the Arduino too.

Comment: I haven't forgotten this, will definitely write an answer soon.

Comment: Also, Raspberry Pi has just [released the Pi Zero](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero/), which costs only $5 (almost incredible imo), together with a $10 WiFi domgle and a $15 LCD, it should not be that expensive, but would require some soldering to get the LCD hooked up.

Comment: My lazy self would probably try to collect old smartphones from friends.

Comment: @JonasCz I just saw that announcement myself, yesterday. Pretty incredible. Those would have plenty of power for what I need. Would you care to roll that into an answer? My soldering skills can manage an LCD.

Comment: @Stefan Also not a bad idea. One which made me think. And I think the main reason I like the custom electronics route is the ability to get tactile buttons and zero turn-on time. The second reason is, of course, that I enjoy building things.

Comment: Yup, will do, in addition to my arduino answer which is almost done and just needs some more research. And soldering wise: you may have to solder on at least part of the GPIO header, so I'm not sure how difficult that is. But if you know you can do it, great !